# Why the email doesn't reach the destination(CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

So the code:

```
        $this->load->library('email');

        $this->email->from('mysite@mysite.com', 'mysite');
        $this->email->to($email); 

        $this->email->subject('Email Test');
        $this->email->message('Testing the email class.');  

        $this->email->send();
```

I can't understand why there is no errors when I send an email, but when I check my email box, there is no emails, so it looks like the email don't reaches his destination, I am using CodeIgniter, maybe i need to add some other settings to fix this?? please help!!

ps: I have also used the native mail() function, anyway the email doesn't comes, I was checking it in gmail

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail
From: "mysite" 
Return-Path: 
Reply-To: "mysite@mysite.kg" 
X-Sender: mysite@mysite.kg
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <501f4f33580d5@mysite.kg>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
=?utf-8?Q?Email_Test?=
Testing the email class.
```

is there something wrong?

Comment: Check your mail server's log to see what happens after PHP hands over the email. Remember, PHP doesn't actually deliver email to the remote mailbox/mail server, all it does is hand it over to a local(ish) SMTP server, and it's that server that's responsible for delivery.

Comment: do u have a mail server?

Comment: the spam is also empty....where can i see that log??

Comment: no I just want to send an email to confirm the registered login of the user, its all i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using this on a localhost server, or on a production server? If you are using your own installation of Apache, PHP and MySQL (such as manual installation, WAMP, XAMPP, MAMP, etc.), then you may not have a mail server installed on your localhost machine for sending mail.

Try the following:

```
mail('you@youremail.com', 'My Subject', 'Test message...');
```

If this does not work, then most likely you do not have a mail server installed on your server.

Comment: i am sendind an email from a real website like www.mysite.com, not localhost

Comment: yes, it returns TRUE, but when i check my email box - is empty :(

Comment: @MisterPHP So you are not even getting emails from the PHP `mail()` function? That appears to me to be an indication that there is most likely something wrong with the server's mail server. You may need to contact your hosting company and find out if you are allowed to send emails from the server, or if there is a problem with their mail server.

Comment: i think also that is the problem of the hosting company, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Strange! May be you should create an file email.php inside config folder.

add the following code in the file

```
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
```

In your controller where you are sending email add a line before you set the to and from headers.

```
$this->load->library('email');
```

to make sure new settings are loaded.